# Bluetooth will not detect previously-removed mouse

Tags: bluetooth

I tried to pair my Logitech Anywhere 2s mouse yesterday; it paired successfully but would not respond, due to a known issue with this device and ubuntu/linux bluetooth pairing. That's not the question here, though.

Today, newly armed with instructions for fixing the unresponsive-mouse problem, I used the Elementary OS bluetooth devices list to *remove* the mouse, then went to re-pair it to start over. Now, it won't show up in the list at all.

I'm getting the same results with bluetoothctl, blueman, and the standard bluetooth window: the device scan runs, other devices are detected properly (my external keyboard paired, is connected and works fine), but the mouse is completely invisible to my Elementary OS system no matter how long I leave the scan running, no matter how many times I put the mouse in pairing mode.

Bluetooth is not blocked, the service is running, and restarting the service has no effect.

I've confirmed that the issue is not the mouse by pairing with other computers running other operating systems, they see it when it goes into pairing mode but Linux does not.

Results from `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'` below, since that was what was asked for in another thread:

```
3a:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
    Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1a56:1535]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci, wl
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:568b Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f3:2234 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0cf3:e301 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[    0.175244] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    2.120501] [drm] GuC firmware load skipped
[    4.371673] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    4.371685] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    4.371687] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    4.371688] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    4.371693] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    4.376383] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[    4.376384] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[    4.376384] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCSP registered
[    4.376385] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol LL registered
[    4.376385] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol ATH3K registered
[    4.376386] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[    4.376416] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Intel registered
[    4.376433] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Broadcom registered
[    4.376434] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol QCA registered
[    4.376434] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol AG6XX registered
[    4.376434] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Marvell registered
[    4.600789] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    4.600790] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    4.600793] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    4.768877] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/pre-cal-pci-0000:3a:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    4.768883] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:3a:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    4.769479] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin failed with error -2
[    4.769480] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin': -2
[    4.770797] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1 api 4 features wowlan,ignore-otp,no-4addr-pad crc32 75dee6c5
[    9.871141] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    9.871146] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    9.871149] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[  769.394550] Bluetooth: hci0 advertising data length corrected
[  844.481555] Bluetooth: hci0 advertising data length corrected
[ 1663.825285] Bluetooth: HIDP (Human Interface Emulation) ver 1.2
[ 1663.825289] Bluetooth: HIDP socket layer initialized
[ 1663.828103] input: Keyboard K380 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:1/0005:046D:B342.0003/input/input26
[ 1663.828302] hid-generic 0005:046D:B342.0003: input,hidraw2: BLUETOOTH HID v42.00 Keyboard [Keyboard K380] on 9c:b6:d0:ec:fe:02
[ 4023.167501] Bluetooth: hci0 advertising data length corrected
[ 4027.037562] Bluetooth: hci0 advertising data length corrected
```

Any help at all would be deeply appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I wish I could say I know why, but the situation is fixed: the mouse is paired properly and works great. About an hour after going through the above I thought to run `hcitool lescan`, and the mouse turned up immediately. Then I realized that it (and many, many other bluetooth devices in the vicinity) were all displaying in the normal scan window, too. So *something* was preventing my computer from seeing many local devices, my mouse included... and then it went away. I may never know what, but everything is now working.